# Error: session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I have this piece of code for github actions

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MuhI.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdIrD.png)

But when I commit, and actions start running, I get this error:

```
ERROR test_LoginErrorMSFunction.py - selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

And this is just under my Install dependencies.
Am I missing something super obvious?
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you share the relevant selenium code in the question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have attached part of the code @Shawn